# Magento2: Issue during setup:di:compile

Tags: magento2

Impossible run command setup:di:compile

```
New version of deployed files: 1538653572
    @s1:~/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html$ php bin/magento setup:di:compile
    The directory "/home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/var/generation/Magento"                          cannot be deleted Warning!rmdir(/home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/var/g                         eneration/Magento): Directory not empty#0 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_h                         tml/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Driver/File.php(403): Magento\Framework\                         Filesystem\Driver\File->deleteDirectory('/home/b2b/domai...')
    #1 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Console/Com                         pilerPreparation.php(68): Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Driver\File->deleteDirect                         ory('/home/b2b/domai...')
    #2 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cl                         i.php(74): Magento\Setup\Console\CompilerPreparation->handleCompilerEnvironment(                         )
    #3 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/bin/magento(22): Magento\Framework\                         Console\Cli->__construct('Magento CLI')
    #4 {main}

    PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Cli' not found in /home/b2b/domains/b2b                         style.pl/public_html/bin/magento:31
    Stack trace:
    #0 {main}
      thrown in /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/bin/magento on line 31

    Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Cli' not found in /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle                         .pl/public_html/bin/magento:31
    Stack trace:
    #0 {main}
      thrown in /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/bin/magento on line 31
    @s1:~/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html$
```

A have try before try deploy and still this issue.

Anyone help how to solve:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Cli' not found in /home/b2b/domains/b2b                         style.pl/public_html/bin/magento:31
    Stack trace:
    #0 {main}
      thrown in /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/bin/magento on line 31

    Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Cli' not found in /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle                         .pl/public_html/bin/magento:31
    Stack trace:
    #0 {main}
      thrown in /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/bin/magento on line 31
```

Comment: try to clear var/di and var/generation folders prior to running compile. does that help?

Comment: What is the magento 2 version you are using?

Comment: Clear var/di and var/generation solved issues. You can give answear